# How to reduce TreeView population time on UI thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm making a media stats application and it has a `TreeView` control with all media files as items. It takes several seconds to populate it and I'm thinking there has to be another way to show items at any scrollbar position without taking that much time.

Accessing controls from threads other than those they were created on (UI thread) is prohibited, so it's either the usual approach with a noticeable freeze, or some other way I can't come up with.

How do I populate a `TreeView` control with many items without stalling the UI thread for a long time?

Comment: If there really are *that* many items, are you sure you want to have them all in one `ListBox`?  Having enough to cause rendering problems  tends to coincide with enough to cause a poor user experience.

Comment: There are no rendering problems though. It just takes about 30 seconds to populate and then it's all smooth and tearless.

Comment: The point is simply that, as a user, trying to search through *that* many items is often cumbersome.  It's often worth finding a way of filtering the list down, possibly through some form of cascading fields (choose a category that can filter down what's shown here) or through some form of pagination.  It's not that you *have* to, just that it might be better than trying to find the 7,346th item in the listbox.

Comment: Actually, a better idea would be to use a ListView or something else that allows tree view, but that control takes even more time to populate. I really should ask about ListView in this case, but I'm still not sure if that's the control to go with.

Comment: That assumes you load it all at once.  Don't do that.  Load only what they can see, and then when each item is expanded, dynamically populate the next level.  When *that* level is expanded, expand one level down, etc.  It's actually a bit more complex to code, but it creates a better user experience.  Populating the listbox without freezing the UI is certainly possible, and in fact reasonably easy, but I just want to be sure you really want to do that.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I changed my question, so you could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't load all of the items at once.  Load only what they need to see at any given point in time (so at first, only the top level), and then when any given item is expanded (there is a relevant event for you to add a handler for), dynamically populate the next level. When an item on that next level is expanded, expand one level down, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Use your UI thread's Dispatcher from another thread with a lower priority.

Or you could implement it differently. Show VMs linked to the Items, which are still loading in the background, and update the VM when the item is finished loading.

Or only load X amount at a time, pages of items.

Comment: You're then freezing the UI thread for a lengthy period of time.  Also, he clearly already knows how to do that.  It's not like he's asking about how to handle cross thread exceptions.